# Multivariable Partition with dplyr

Tags: r, partitioning

I have a large data frame with over 1 million observations. Two of my independent variables `A` and `B` have 18 and 72 numerically labelled categories respectively. For simplicity sake, assume the categories are labelled `1-18` and `1-72`. I'd like to partition all of my data into 36 groups of 6, `(A 1-6 with B 1-6, A 1-6 with B 7-12, etc.)`
Currently, I am using dplyr's `mutate` with 36 nested ifelse statements, such as `mutate(partition = ifelse(A <= 6 & B <= 6, 1, ifelse(...)))` but this is tedious and difficult to change should I want to make partitions of different sizes.

Another way of describing it is that there are `18 * 72 = 1296` unique combinations of parameter A and B, but I would like to partition these 1296 into 36 groups of 36 observations, with the flexibility to change the number of observations and groups.

I really feel like there should be a better way to partition my data, but nothing comes to mind immediately. The only other idea I have is to use `expand.grid` and use a join of sorts. What other methods exist that allow me to partition my data?

The below example is kind of how I would like my data to appear.

```
A    B    Partition
1    1    1
1    2    1
1    3    1
1    4    1
1    5    1
1    6    1
2    1    1
...  ...  ...
6    6    1
7    1    2
...  ...  ...
12   71   12
12   72   12
13   1    13
...  ...  ...
18   70   36
18   71   36
18   72   36
```

Comment: Adding your data would be helpful. But `case_when()` within `mutate` might be helpful

Comment: The data is too large to add here, but I think I can show a workaround. `case_when()` looks like it make the `mutate()` function a lot cleaner, but still rather tedious to make changes in partition size, which I will be doing.